# How to apply my font in RichTextBox regardless of what fonts the .rtf source use?

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, richtextbox, non-ascii-characters

This seems to be a simple task but I can't find a resource to solve. In a fresh new solution I create a single richtextbox, and add only one source for it with:

```cs
richTextBox1.LoadFile(".\\test.rtf");
```

The fonts used in `test.rtf` are vary, but I don't care. I try this but it doesn't work:

```cs
this.richTextBox1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("SVN-Avo", 9F);
```

I then try:

```cs
richTextBox1.LoadFile(".\\test.rtf", RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
richTextBox1.SelectAll();
richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("SVN-Avo", 12);
richTextBox1.DeselectAll();
```

but the output is like this:
[image]

I see that in the source those non-ASCII characters are assigned to another font, but let's leave it to another question¹. For now, regardless of how the fonts are used in the source, the code should ignore them altogether. But it doesn't.

I should note that the font I use should be fully supported in those characters. In simple textbox all characters are displayed properly.

Is there a way to force the output to use my font?

<sub>¹ [How does WordPad deal with fonts in RTF files with non-ASCII characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74823892/3416774)</sub>

Comment: SelectAll(), assign SelectionFont, DeselectAll()

Comment: It doesn't work ([image](https://i.imgur.com/bGW3Tw5.png)). The rtf file is strange as it use a different font for some non-ASCII characters, but the the code should overwrite it nevertheless

Comment: Use a font that has glyphs for these Vietnamese characters.  If this is XP then install support for East Asian languages.

Comment: I have updated the question regarding this. Can you take a look?

Answer (score -1):

```
// Assume that 'richTextBox' is a RichTextBox control
richTextBox.LoadFile("file.rtf", RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
    
// Select the first character in the RichTextBox
richTextBox.SelectionStart = 0;
richTextBox.SelectionLength = 1;
    
// Set the font for the selected text to Arial
richTextBox.SelectionFont = new Font("Arial", 12);
```

Comment: I have updated the question regarding this. Can you take a look?